# Последовательность. Максимумы и минимумы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не знаю как реализовать:

Дано натуральное число `n` и целые числа  `х1` `х2` `х3`... `х`. Какое число в последовательности чисел `x` встретится раньше: максимальное или минимальное? Если максимальных и минимальных чисел несколько, то должны учитываться первые из них.

Comment: @Евгений нашел ошибку в коде,почему то всегда пишет что минимальны элемент встречается первым

Comment: @Евгений ответ дал

Comment: Какую роль играет в вашем вопросе натуральное число `n`? Количество целых чисел?

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input('N > '))
x = [int(input(f'x[{i}] > ')) for i in range(n)]

x_ = sorted(x)
if x_[0] == x_[-1]:
  print('Все числа последовательности равны')
else:
  for i in x:
    if i == x_[0]:
      print('Минимальный элемент встречается раньше')
      break
    elif i == x_[-1]:
      print('Максимальный элемент встречается раньше')
      break
```

Входные данные:

```
N > 7
x[0] > 1
x[1] > 3
x[2] > 5
x[3] > -5
x[4] > 4
x[5] > 7
x[6] > 2
```

Результат:

```
Минимальный элемент встречается раньше
```

Comment: в данном коде ошибка ,всегда выводиться минимальное число,не могли бы вы посмотреть?

Comment: @nikitahelp укажите, что в нём не так - я исправлю ошибку

Comment: ответ дал,всегда выводится минимальный елемент(что он встречается раньше)

Comment: @nikitahelp обновил ответ. Вторую строку измените, и будет работать. Прошу прощения, забыл, что строки нужно переводить в числа

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/Nm4G5b

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

l = min(a)
r = max(a)

if l == r:
  print('All elements are euqal')
else:
  for x in a:
    if x == l:
      print('Min is earlier')
      break
    elif x == r:
      print('Max is earlier')
      break
```